# Python: How to draw a new and different set of cards for a card game?

Tags: python

Im looking for some help regarding a simple card game i am working on. The premise is:

- 30 cards shuffled in a deck containing colors Red, Blue and Yellow each having numbers 1-10
- 2 players receive a card from the top of this deck
- Certain colors will beat another one
- The winner is given both played cards
- The process repeats until there is no ore cards left in the deck.

My problem is that i cant figure out a way to have new cards drawn once the first go has ended. my code instead calls upon the cards that have already been played (which causes an error). is there any efficient way i could have new cards drawn while working with my code? Thanks.

```
import random

Deck = ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4', 'Y5', 'Y6', 'Y7', 'Y8', 'Y9', 'Y10', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10']
random.shuffle(Deck)
print(Deck)

Player1Card = Deck[0]
print("Player One, Your Card Is {0}" .format(Deck[0]))
Player2Card = Deck[1]
print("Player Two, Your Card Is {0}" .format(Deck[1]))

PlayerOneScore = 0
PlayerTwoScore = 0
GameCount = 0
PlayerOneCardList = list()
PlayerTwoCardList = list()


1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < 4
4 < 5
5 < 6
7 < 8
8 < 9
9 < 10

while GameCount == 0:

if "R" in Player1Card and "B" in Player2Card:
    print("Player One Wins")
    PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore+2
    print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))
    PlayerOneCardList.append(Player1Card)
    PlayerOneCardList.append(Player2Card)

    print("Player 1, These Are Your Currently Held Cards:")
    print(PlayerOneCardList)
    print("Player 2, These Are Your Currently Held Cards:")
    print(PlayerTwoCardList)

    Deck.remove(Player1Card)
    Deck.remove(Player2Card)


elif "R" in Player2Card and "B" in Player1Card:
    print("Player Two Wins")
    PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore+2
    print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))

elif "B" in Player1Card and "Y" in Player2Card:
    print("Player One Wins")
    PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore+2
    print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))

elif "B" in Player2Card and "Y" in Player1Card:
    print("Player Two Wins")
    PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore+2
    print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))

elif "Y" in Player1Card and "R" in Player2Card:
    print("Player One Wins")
    PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore+2
    print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))

elif "Y" in Player2Card and "R" in Player1Card:
    print("Player Two Wins")
    PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore+2
    print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))






elif "Y" in Player1Card and "Y" in Player2Card:
    if Player1Card > Player2Card:
        print("Player One Wins")
        PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore+2
        print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))
    elif Player1Card < Player2Card:
        print("Player Two Wins")
        PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore+2
        print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))







elif "B" in Player1Card and "B" in Player2Card:
    if Player1Card > Player2Card:
        print("Player One Wins")
        PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore+2
        print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))
    elif Player1Card < Player2Card:
        print("Player Two Wins")
        PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore+2
        print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))








elif "R" in Player1Card and "R" in Player2Card:
    if Player1Card > Player2Card:
        print("Player One Wins")
        PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore+2
        print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))
    elif Player1Card < Player2Card:
        print("Player Two Wins")
        PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore+2
        print("Player One, your score is {0} and Player Two, your score is {1}" . format(PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore))



if PlayerOneScore + PlayerTwoScore == 30:
    if PlayerOneScore > PlayerTwoScore:
        print("Player One Wins")
        print("The game is over")
        gamecount = 1
    elif PlayerTwoScore > PlayerOneScore:
        print("Player Two Wins")
        print("The game is over")
        gamecount = 1
else:
    gamecont1  = input("Would you like to continue the game Y for yes or N for no?")
    if gamecont1 == "Y" or "y":
        gamecont = 0
    else:
        gamecont = 1
```

Comment: I haven't thoroughly read your question but I would recommend taking a look at http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c5/s4.html

Comment: I see you remove the cards in one case, but not all. Instead, consider functions to handle a task, so you make your code easy to follow and debug. Also consider pop when they first get their card, instead of removing it later. https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the `.remove()` statement right after you draw the cards like this

```
Player1Card = Deck[0]
print("Player One, Your Card Is {0}" .format(Deck[0]))
Player2Card = Deck[1]
print("Player Two, Your Card Is {0}" .format(Deck[1]))

Deck.remove(Player1Card)
Deck.remove(Player2Card)
```

This makes sure that the current card will not be in the round of card picking.

Hope this helps